# How to return multiple results from SqlConnection using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have working code which I have listed below here it does exactly what I want. However, I would like to minimize it down so I only call the DB once instead of twice.  I currently have the query written to only bring back 1 record that has 1 column.

This column brings back a date which I use in my code.  The issues is I also need to bring back the user as well. Which I made work by basically using the same query but have it bring back the user rather than the date.

THE BIG QUESTION:
I have the query to use to bring back both pieces of information, however, I am not sure how to get the information back to use in my code?  when there is more that one column being returned from query.  **side note** the new query still only brings back one record but with 2 columns.

THE WORKING CODE:
I would add in "UpdatedBy" to last select statement to add the 2nd column.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\......");
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                string updatedOn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = ("USE CORNERSTONE DECLARE @SID int SET @SID = " + SupplierId + "; "  +
                "with MaxDate as " +
                "(select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy, SupplierId from CORNERSTONE.Suppliers.Supplier where SupplierId = @SID " +
                "UNION " +
                "select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy, SupplierId from Suppliers.CompanyLocation where SupplierId = @SID " +
                "UNION " +
                "select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy, SupplierId from Suppliers.AssignedContact where SupplierId = @SID) " +
                "select UpdatedOn " +
                "from MaxDate " +
                "where UpdatedOn = (Select MAX(UpdatedOn) from MaxDate)");

                updatedOn = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                DateTime ParsedDateTime = DateTime.Parse(updatedOn);
                AuditUpdatedOn = ParsedDateTime;

                conn.Close();
```

Comment: btw: you should pass `SID` in as a *parameter* rather than using concatenation - safer *and* more efficient (query plan reuse, etc)  - i.e. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", SupplierId);` (goes back to trying to understand what the code is doing)

Comment: also: pro tip - use a verbatim string literal for SQL, then you don't need to keep doing newlines with quotes and `+` just `@" ... "` with the `...` *including* newlines

Comment: NOTED thanks I'll mess around with that. see what I can do to add that in.

Comment: Why are you using ExecuteScalar which only returns one column when you are selecting multiple columns? See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: well the reasoning for that is i was having a hard time figuring it out how to get info any other way that would actually work I'll check to link to see if I can get more info I failed to find when creaating

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677191/how-to-get-multiple-rows-from-datareader

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want the `UpdatedBy` from the query; if so, this *should* just be:

```cs
cmd.CommandText = @"
with MaxDate as (
    select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from CORNERSTONE.Suppliers.Supplier where SupplierId = @SID
    union select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from Suppliers.CompanyLocation where SupplierId = @SID
    union select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from Suppliers.AssignedContact where SupplierId = @SID
)
select top 1 UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy
from MaxDate 
where UpdatedOn = (Select MAX(UpdatedOn) from MaxDate)
";
```

However, the *problem* comes from the fact that you now have two columns to read, so `ExecuteScalar` isn't useful. There are two options:

1. use `ExecuteReader` and use the read API, or
2. cheat and get a tool to do it all for you

On the second, frankly: this is a perfect scenario for ["Dapper"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/):

```cs
(var when, var who) = conn.QuerySingle<(DateTime, string)>(@"
with MaxDate as (
    select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from CORNERSTONE.Suppliers.Supplier where SupplierId = @SID
    union select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from Suppliers.CompanyLocation where SupplierId = @SID
    union select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from Suppliers.AssignedContact where SupplierId = @SID
)
select top 1 UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy
from MaxDate 
where UpdatedOn = (Select MAX(UpdatedOn) from MaxDate)
", new { SID = SupplierId });
```

and then `when` and `who` should be populated. You might want to think about whether you need `QuerySingleOrDefault` in case there are no rows.

**Usually**, when you use `Query[First/Single/etc]<T>` with Dapper, the `T` is mapped using column names (to populate an object model), but it detects value-tuples (`(DateTime, string)` is a value-tuple) and treats them by position instead.

---

If you have to use raw ADO.NET - something *like* the following:

```cs
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"
with MaxDate as (
select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from CORNERSTONE.Suppliers.Supplier where SupplierId = @SID
union select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from Suppliers.CompanyLocation where SupplierId = @SID
union select UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy from Suppliers.AssignedContact where SupplierId = @SID
);
select top 1 UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy
from MaxDate 
where UpdatedOn = (Select MAX(UpdatedOn) from MaxDate)
";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p.ParameterName = "@SID";
    p.Value = SupplierId;
    p.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            var who = reader.GetDateTime(0);
            var when = reader.GetString(1);
            // *** HERE *** we now know the answers
        }
        else
        {
            // what to do if we don't get anyone?
        }
        do // need to consume entire TDS to
        { // make sure we see errors
            while (reader.Read()) { }
        } while (reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I will try these out along with your other advice and see what happens!

Comment: @RodeoEmpire note: if you use Dapper (the second example), the parameterization is even easier - see example

Comment: @RodeoEmpire I also added an example using raw ADO.NET - frankly, my advice here is "just use Dapper" (although I'm perhaps biased, but after 44 million downloads it can't be *entirely* wrong)